# How to resize image in slider?

Tags: wordpress, image, resize, slider

[Here's the website that I'm creating](http://www.awcorner.ayz.pl/)

My images are auto resized in the slider, however in my case it doesn't work properly because my images are vertical.
I need little help with this.

I also want my posts to be higher for the same reason.

I've tried many options in wordpress configuration site. 
If I have to write my own code to reach my goal, where I should start?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO is not the place to ask this question. Please ask the theme developer.

Comment: I've asked on developer forum. I didn't get any response, hence I asked here. I'll try to contact support.

Comment: Create a sub-theme of your existing theme. Play with the css.

Comment: You can add this css to the additional css in your customizer (it's near the bottom). https://jsbin.com/rumoyis/edit?css It would be better to swap out that slider for something else because it looks bad. If you need a slider, I would use another one and create images that are appropriate for a short and and wide format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I visit your site. Image size is small according to the slider. Try following CSS.

background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

[image: Click here to see the result]